# PHP spreadsheet - Column string index can not be longer than 3 characters

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I get error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Exception: Column
> string index can not be longer than 3 characters in
> /var/www/html/domain.com/phpspreadsheet/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Coordinate.php:305
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/domain.com/phpspreadsheet/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.php(1430):
> PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString() #1
> /var/www/html/domain.com/exceltests.php(393):
> PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet->getColumnDimension() #2
> {main} thrown in
> /var/www/html/domain.com/phpspreadsheet/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Coordinate.php
> on line 305

And this is the line #393 in my file:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("B$i")->setWidth(90);
```

**EDIT** More code:

```
$blob = returnItemImageOnly($pdo, $row["item"]);

if($blob){

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("B$i")->setWidth(90); 
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension("$i")->setRowHeight(80);        

    $type = $blob['type'];
    $image = base64_encode($blob['image']);

    $imgdata = base64_decode($image);
    $mimetype = getImageMimeType($imgdata);

    $fname = "tmp/".rand(). ".".$mimetype;
    $forUnlink[] = $fname;

    file_put_contents($fname, $imgdata);
    $drawing = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing(); 

    $drawing->setPath($fname);

    $drawing->setCoordinates("B$i");

    $drawing->setResizeProportional(false);

    $drawing->setWidth(75);

    $drawing->setHeight(75);

    $drawing->setOffsetX(34);
    $drawing->setOffsetY(15);   

    $drawing->setWorksheet($sheet);

}

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("B$i:C$i");
```

I searched for possible issues but no luck! 
Maybe someone had the same issue? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am wondering what `$i` could be this time

Comment: @qrsngky it is number in loop from 13 - so B13

Comment: Why would you call `getColumnDimension` with such a value to begin with? This should get _only_ the column identifier passed, and no row.

Comment: @CBroe cells from B13 contains image - B13 is merged column with C13

Comment: You say "is", as if that was the case already at that point - but you do the merging only at the very end of the code you have shown. Plus, I don't think the library is equipped to handle that -`getColumnDimension` wants a column only, and nothing more. The width of your two merged cells in that row, will be the width of column B plus the width of C, trying to set it separately for the merged columns, that doesn't even make much sense.

Comment: @CBroe id did work on smaller document but when i get document with more lines it stopped working. ..

Comment: I just find out that it stops working at loop 90 row. .. Line looks good. ..